# How can I reference the id in a sequence object created by the TraMineR library in R?

Tags: r, traminer

Working with the TraMineR library in R I create a sequence object. The first column of the data contains an id which I use in the sequence definition:

```
>library(TraMineR)
>load("data.RData")
>data.seq <- seqdef(data, 2:5, id=data$id)
```

When I look at the names of the columns of the sequence object (data.seq), "id" is not listed--only the names of the columns that have the sequence states in them. How can I reference the id in the data.seq object?

The reason for this is that I want to randomly reorder the rows of the sequence object and still be able to pull the "id" out of the sequence object.

Comment: Try `str(data.seq)`. There may be some items that are not directly included in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Had to dig in the documentation to get a clue that this is how it can be done:

```
id <- rownames(data.seq)
```

Comment: Actually, the `seqdef` help page clearly states that the optional `id`argument is 'for setting the rownames of the sequence object'. And `rownames` is the usual function that returns the row names of an R object when applicable.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out myself after some more digging.